# $'a'$ for which roots of one equation lie between roots of other equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

If the range of values of $'a'$ for which the roots of the equation $x^2-2x-a^2+1=0$ lie between the roots of the equation $x^2-2(a+1)x+a(a-1)=0$ is $(p,q)$, find the value of $(q+\frac{1}{p^2})$

Could someone give me slight hint as I can't understand how to initiate.

Comment: If you treat a as a constant $x^2 - 2x -a^2 +1 = 0$ has two roots. Solve them using the quadratic formula.  $x^2-2(a+1)x + a(a-1) = 0$ has two roots solve them.   You have four roots expressed in terms of a.  For different values of 'a' these roots will have different values.  for some values the roots of the first equation will be between the roots of the second.  Find the range of values of "a" where this is true.  Find the lowest value where this is true.  Find the highest value where this is true.  Then, just to be weird, add the lowest to the reciprical of the square of the highest.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2-2x-a^2+1=0$.  Quadratic equation yields $x = \frac{2\pm \sqrt{4 - 4(a^+ 1)}}{2}$

$x^2-2(a+1)x+a(a-1)=0$.  Q.E. yields $x = \frac{2(a+1) \pm \sqrt{(2(a+1))^2 - 4a(a-1)}}{2}$

We are told $\frac{2(a+1) - \sqrt{(2(a+1))^2 - 4a(a-1)}}{2}< \frac{2- \sqrt{4 - 4(a^+ 1)}}{2}$ and $\frac{2+ \sqrt{4 - 4(a^+ 1)}}{2} <\frac{2(a+1) + \sqrt{(2(a+1))^2 - 4a(a-1)}}{2}$

We work that out to figure that $p \le a \le q$.  Then we evaluate $p + 1/q^2$.

Comment: Root of first equation is $1 \pm |a|$ so do we have to makes cases for modulus?